# HTTPS requests PHP/ ZF 1.11

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, https

I need to implement a setting secure browsing to my site. I have SSL certificate for my site and I want it should work for both HTTP and HTTPS requests based on the user setting. If user selects secure browsing it should redirect with HTTPS protocol only though if any one remove https manually in url like facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your bootstrap file

```
protected function _initForceSSL() {
 if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') {
  header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit();
}
```

and for detail

or you can also use for some pages

[https request on some pages but not on all pages zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777459/https-request-on-some-pages-but-not-on-all-pages-zend-framework)

*i am not associated with above link for any firm*

hope this will sure work for you.